# How to include an interaction term between two categorical variables in statsmodels' mixed linear model?

Tags: python, statsmodels, mixed-models

I try to include an interaction between two categorical variables in a mixed linear model calculated with python's statsmodels. However, I get a "LinAlgError: Singular matrix" Error. Please find a small example, which reproduces the error below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

d = {'V1' : pd.Series(["ONE","TWO","THREE","ONE","TWO","THREE","ONE","TWO","THREE","THREE"]),
     'V2' : pd.Series(["GREEN", "GREEN","RED", "BLUE","BLUE","RED","RED","RED", "RED", "BLUE"]),
     'V3' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2.]),
     'V4' : pd.Series(["X", "XX", "X", "XX","X","X","XX","XX","X","XX"])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

mod = smf.mixedlm(formula='V3 ~ V1 * V2', data=df, groups=df["V4"])
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

When I change the last value of V2 from "BLUE" to "GREEN" the code works. Even without changing the values of V2 an OLS regression provide plausible results:

```
mod = smf.ols(formula='V3 ~ V1 * V2', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

My question is, why does mixedlm produce this error and how can I avoid it (of course without changing the data)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you have too many empty cells, i.e. combination of categorical variables that have no observations. OLS works because it uses a generalized inverse (pinv) that produces an estimate even when the design matrix is singular. This does not work in general outside the OLS/WLS linear models.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. To overcome this problem I am creating "interaction variables" by dummifying the variables and multiplying each column with one another. After that, I delete the columns with 0 variances and use the new variables for estimation.